# Replacing basement door and walls with a hatch

Tags: doors, basement, removal

I'm trying to remove the structure that leads to the basement. (see sketch 1).

[image]

Once removed, there will be an empty space like (see sketch 2)

My aim is to build over it, a simple door (see sketch 3 below)

[image]

What are other solutions for that door (regardless good or bad), please?

As you can see from my sketches, I'm trying to gain space.

Thanks

Comment: "Trap doors" were traditional for access to root cellars; I've seen them used for access to store basements too. You'd need to check whether that would pass residential construction codes in your area.

Comment: Hi @keshlam , Thanks alhtough not needed in France http://france.angloinfo.com/housing/building-property/building-planning-permission/

Comment: @AndyK, this is an interior door or hatch as it appears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build a sloped frame and hinged doors, as @keshlam suggests, this is the traditional style. There are manufactured options that are actually rather reasonably priced. http://www.dashwindows.com/bilco-doors.php

[image]

Comment: In the US, that's often known as "bulkhead doors". I wasn't sure from the description whether this was indoor or outdoor access.

Comment: @keshlam yes I was thinking of a hatch door

Comment: @AndyK Hatch door leaves it a bit vague, but if this interior access the term you are probably seeking is "trap door" - meaning a section of floor, which can be walked upon,  that is also a doorway to below the floor. If that's what you are talking about, I don't think there's any real alternate to that that works the same. Your sketch does not make clear if it's exterior (which the bulkhead would suit) or interior.